# Как сделать так, чтоб при наведении увеличивался масштаб изображения, НО при этом сам элемент не выходил за назначенные ему границы?

Tags: html, css, transform, overflow, scale

Как сделать так, чтоб при наведении увеличивался масштаб изображения, НО при этом сам элемент по прежнему оставался 300рх и не выходил за назначенные ему границы?

Почему в данном случае не действует ни `width`, ни `overflow`?

```css
.photo {
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FRWfmD7p/3fb60ef7936531a414af177f842a18f6.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: не тому элементу установлен `overflow`, это свойство надо устанавливать контейнеру, а не содержимому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не тому элементу установлен `overflow`, это свойство надо устанавливать контейнеру, а не содержимому.

```css
.photo {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FRWfmD7p/3fb60ef7936531a414af177f842a18f6.jpg" alt=""></div>
```